# Map key exists and value is larger than 0

Tags: elixir

I have to check if a map has a key and if the value of that key is larger than 0. Currently I use this code:

`if Map.has_key?(portfolio, stock) && Map.get(portfolio, stock) > 0 do`

I am wondering if there is an easier/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if Map.has_key?(portfolio, stock) && Map.get(portfolio, stock) > 0 do` is unsafe, because [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) terms can be [compared against each other](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/operators.html#term-ordering).

```elixir
iex||1 ▸ [] > 0            
#⇒ true
```

That said, the safest way would be to pattern match with guards using [`Kernel.match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2)

```elixir
match?(%{stock: stock} when stock > 0, portfolio)
```

To make it bullet-proof against wrong input, make the guard stricter.

```elixir
match?(%{stock: stock} when is_number(stock) and stock > 0, portfolio)
```

```elixir
iex||2 ▸ [%{stock: 3}, %{stock: 0}, %{}, %{stock: []}]
...||2 ▸ |> Enum.filter(&match?(%{stock: stock} when is_number(stock) and stock > 0, &1))
#⇒[%{stock: 3}]
```

---

*Sidenote:* logical conjunction of two *booleans* is idiomatically written with `and` not `&&`. The latter is to be used for non-strict conjunction, where `nil` can be treated as `falsey` and `42` as `truthy` values.